# Удаление элементов из коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть абстрактный класс `Shape`:

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public string Name {get;set}
}
```

И различные классы фигур, которые наследуются от `Shape` — `Triangle`, `Circle`, `Square`.

Также имеется коллекция фигур, которая привязывается к `ListBox`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Shape> Shapes{get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<Shape>()
{
  new Triangle {Name = "Треугольник"},
  new Circle {Name = "Круг"},
  new Circle {Name = "Круг"},
  new Square {Name = "Квадрат"},
}
```

Каждый объект в `ListBox` представлен свойством `Name` объекта и кнопкой, к которой биндится команда удаления элемента из коллекции. 
Команда одна для всех элементов.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="x" 
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveShapeCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Вопрос в следующем: 
У элементов могут быть одинаковые свойства. Как в таком случае искать нужный элемент, который требуется удалить?

Есть ли возможность получать индекс элемента, который вызвал команду?

Comment: Я думаю самый простой вариант для вас это добавить еще одно поле GUID или ID. Или же можно передавать сам элемент через Comman parameter и получать элемент из параметров метода комманды RemoveShapeCommand. Еще можно использовать SelectedItem, если вам такой вариант подойдет

Comment: @user2455111, С Id вариант, да. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас не перегружена функция `Equals`, проще всего удалять [по самому элементу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx). Индекс не нужен практически никогда. При удалении нужный элемент будет определяться при помощи `Equals`, а значит, одинаковые свойства или нет, приниматься во внимание не будет.

Comment: Не знал этого. Спасибо!

Comment: @maxwellL Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Этот вариант для удаления нескольких параметров. Если же у вашего грида запрешено выделение нескольких строк и вы удаляете по одной строке. То используйте свойство SelectedItem для грида:

```
var tempItem = SelectedItem;
SelectedItem = myList.FirstOrDefault();
myList.Remove(tempItem);
```

Иначе:

xaml

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyGridName, 
Path=SelectedItems}" Width="100" Margin="10" />
```

command

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand
      {
         get
         {
            return
               _deleteCommand ?? (_deleteCommand = new CollectionCommandDelegate<MyListType>(
                  collection =>
                  {
                     var myDeleteParameters = collection != null ? collection.ToArray() : null;
                     if(myDeleteParameters!= null)
                     foreach(var myparam in myDeleteParameters)
                       myList.Remove(myparam);
                  };
         }
      }
```

ну и CollectionCommandDelegate 
 public class CollectionCommandDelegate : ICommand
   {
        private readonly Action> _invoker;
        private readonly Func, bool> _predicate;
        private bool _hasChange;

```
    public CollectionCommandDelegate(Action<IEnumerable<T>> invoker)
    {
       _invoker = invoker;
       _predicate = arg => true;
    } 

    public CollectionCommandDelegate(Action<IEnumerable<T>> invoker, Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool> predicate)
      {
         _invoker = invoker;
         _predicate = predicate;
      }

      public void Execute(object parameter)
      {
         _invoker.Invoke(getParameter(parameter));
      }

      public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
      {
         var newState = _predicate.Invoke(getParameter(parameter));
         if (newState != _hasChange)
         {
            _hasChange = newState;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
               CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
         return _hasChange;
      }

      private IEnumerable<T> getParameter(object parameter)
      {
         return ((IEnumerable)parameter).Cast<T>();
      }

      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
   }
```